# How to prevent emails from a specific address going to Hotmail SPAM?

Tags: spam, hotmail, email-spam, spf

I have a site on a dedicated server with it's own IP range that has been running for a good few years. We have a notification email address (mailout@domain.com) which we use to send automated emails (activation emails when a user signs up and notification emails if something relevant to them happens, eg someone befriends them or comments on their picture etc). Users can select whether to receive these notifications or not. We have SPF and RDNS setup.

Email from all our other email accounts go to hotmail/gmail/yahoo mail etc correctly into the inbox. However any mail sent from the mailout@domain.com account (whether automatically by the server or manually via outlook) is delivered correctly to the inboxes for yahoo and gmail however goes into Junk in Hotmail (but other @domain.com addresses deliver to hotmail's inbox correctly). It says at the top of the message that MS Smartscreen marked this message as junk. I signed up for MS Smart Network Data Services to monitor the IP and it says it's not blocked but it displays Bot-like behaviour (which kind of makes sense as our notifications are kind of bot like even though they're not spam).

I can't work out what to do to prevent this from happening, we've authenticated the email, there's obviously not a general block on the IP as emails from different accounts on the same domain are going through successfully. It doesn't seem to be the format of the email either because if I send identical emails from mailout@domain.com and contact@domain then the one from contact@ gets through to the inbox but the one from mailout@ goes through to junk.

I can't really work out what to do and obviously trying to get MS to sort it out is never going to happen and i've used all their available tools. I can obviously try setting up a new email address (eg noreply@domain.com) and using that for notifications but i assume it will only be a matter of time before that gets blocked as well.

I would be immensely grateful for any suggestions anyone has!

Thanks so much,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You don't have many options.  Try to do as many of the following as you can:

1. Reach out to MS support (don't discard this notion)
2. Implement [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and possibly [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) (which are vastly more informative than [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework))
3. Change your IP address to something cleaner
4. Find and follow bulk sender best practices, e.g. [M³AAWG's BCPs](https://www.m3aawg.org/published-documents), perhaps the [Help – I'm on a Blocklist](https://www.m3aawg.org/sites/maawg/files/news/M3AAWG_Blocklist_Help_BP_2014-06.pdf) doc